# Are Western Digital SSDs compatible with QNAP TS-469U-RP NAS?

Tags: ssd, network-attached-storage, qnap

I just purchased a QNAP TS-469U-RP NAS.  It is my understanding that just about any SSD will be compatible to work in a NAS, as long as the make and model of all four drives are identical.  That being said, QNAP has a web-page listing all hard drives, which have been tested with the TS-469U-RP and are known to be compatible, as shown in the following screenshot.

[image: QNAP's "recommended" list of SSDs]

I want to purchase four Western Digital 1TB Green SSD (model # WDS100T3G0A), simply because I have used them in the past and found WD drives to be reliable.  Is there any reason why I should not use the Western Digital SSDs just mentioned in my QNAP TS-469U-RP?  If so, why?

P.S. I do see that I can submit a request to QNAP asking them to test the Western Digital drives, but that will likely take time and I would like to get this done ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical reason why the drives wouldn't work in the NAS.
The reason you should not use drives which aren't listed on the compatibility list is that QNAP will refuse any support if you do.

Specifically, if you open a support call with QNAP for whatever problem, and the support finds any component in your NAS that isn't on their compatibility list, they will close the support call because you are using an unsupported configuration.

Since vendor support for all components is essential in a business environment, this is a compelling reason to use only components on the official compatibility list even if there isn't any technical necessity.